# How to restrict certain things to admins in gmod 13

Tags: server-administration, garrys-mod

I have a GMOD 13 server and I want to know how to restrict things to admins on it.
URestrict wouldn't work with gmod 13, so I have no options. I have come here for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you are looking at restricting playermodels or anything in a pointshop, I found a solution here: http://pointshop.burt0n.net/items/properties.

This may not help with things outside of pointshop, but this worked for me. Particularly this line:

`ITEM.AllowedUserGroups = { "admin", "vip" }`

Answer (score 0):

If URestrict won't work. Why not try ULX's version? [URS](http://forums.ulyssesmod.net/index.php?topic=5269.0). This is different to URestrict and this is links with the ULX Admin Mod.